# Python: can I use the lambda argument n to repeat lambda operation (n+n) n times?

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to code-golf a Python function that takes a parameter n and squares it without pow, * or **. I am at this stage:

```
square = lambda n: n+n
```

Can I iterate n+n n times using about 10 more characters?

Comment: `lambda x: sum(x for x in range(x))`?

Comment: Cool, thank you so much. I had to use i as a counter though, not x.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That won't work if you're reusing `x` as the loop variable.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, my bad. I wrote it in haste. It should actually have been `lambda x: sum(x for _ in range(x))`, or `n` or whichever.

Comment: use `int.__pow__(4,2)` instead, no `pow` ;) BTW I'm not sure arbitrary golfing constraints are normally on-topic for SO

Comment: By code-golfing I meant 'using the least amount of characters possible' and not an actual code-golf competition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sqr = lambda n : sum(n for i in range(n))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> sqr(9)
81
>>> sqr(12)
144
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036224/python-can-i-use-the-lambda-argument-n-to-repeat-lambda-operation-nn-n-times#comment81018655_47036224

Comment: that's different and WRONG

Comment: Yeah, the loop variable had to be different, but same principle.

Comment: didn't notice you've commented though, was preparing some outputs for the  answer.

Comment: Yeah, since you mentioned the right answer (before I did), it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with lambda:

```
x = lambda y, c:y+y + x(y, c+1) if c< 10 else 0
print(x(10, 0))
```

Output:

```
200
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with recursion, a conditional expression and a default argument:

```
square = lambda n, i=0: n + square(n, i + 1) if n > i else 0
square(10)  # 100
```

I suppose this probably only works for positive numbers ... but could be made to work with negative numbers with some judicious absolute values:

```
square = lambda n, i=0: abs(n) + square(n, i + 1) if abs(n) > i else 0
```

Answer (score 1):

as @mgilson said, you can do it with recursion and lambdas:

```
square = lambda n, m=0: 0 if n==m else n+square(n,m+1)
```

the important thing is to carry the result with you in each step

Answer (score 0):

`square =  lambda n : sum([n]*n)`

Edited : (without using * or **)

`square = lambda n : n+sum(range(2,n+n,2))`

Comment: But it has `*` which OP doesn't want.

Comment: I've read COLDSPEED's comment and instantly figured out the same solution as Ashish later suggested. Thanks to both of you. The last suggestion indeed is not useful as uses * and does not solve the problem. Unfortunately I cannot yet up or down-vote.

Comment: Ohh my bad, how about this :
`square =  lambda n : n+sum(range(2,n+n,2))`

Comment: Thank you all. Lambda makes more sense to me.

Comment: I did vote up your solution as soon as you have posted it.

Comment: @KatiaPunter no i mean there's a tick for marking what you think is the correct answer.

Comment: @AshishRanjan I would have never realised it was a tick! Thanks! Ticked.